# How can I get the same piece (duplicate code) of an image from many different photos every time?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, image-recognition

From 5000 photos of license plates I want to determine which duplicate code these license plates have.

Here are 2 examples of a duplicate code on a license plate.

- [image]
- [image]

In the first example the duplicate code is 2 and in the second example the duplicate code is 1.

With the package Magick and Tesseract, see code below, I was able to retrieve the piece of the photo from the first example where the duplicate code is and to read the duplicate code. Only in the second example and other photos is the photo different.

So I am looking for something that can recognize where the duplicate code is and that will read the duplicate code. Note: The duplicate code is **always above** the 1st indent mark.

Does someone have an idea how to read the duplicate code automatically from 5000 different photos?

```
library(magick)
library(tesseract)

#Load foto:
foto <- image_read("C:/Users/camie/OneDrive/Documenten/kenteken3.jpg")

 #Get piece of photo where duplicate code is retrieved:
foto2 <- image_crop(foto,"10X24-620-170")

#read duplicate code:
cat(ocr(foto3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach based on the package `EBImage`. ImageMagik is great for image manipulation but I think `EBImage` may provide more quantitative tools that are useful here. As for all image processing, the quality of input image matters a great deal. The approach suggested here would likely benefit from noise and artifact removal, scaling and possibly cropping.

Also, some licenses seem to have additional symbols in the position of interest that are not numbers. Clearly more pre-processing and filtering are needed for such cases.

#### Sample image

[image: sample 1]

```
# Starting from EBImage
  if (!require(EBImage)) {
    source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
    biocLite("EBImage")
    library(EBImage)
  }

# Test images
#   setwd(<image directory>)
    f1 <- "license1.jpg"
    f2 <- "license2.jpg"
    
# Read image and convert to normalized greyscale
  img0 <- readImage(f1)
  img <- channel(img0, "grey")
  img <- normalize(img)
# plot(img) # insert plot or display commands as desired

# Rudimentary image process for ~300 pixel wide JPEG
  xmf <- medianFilter(img, 1)
  xgb <- gblur(xmf, 1)
  xth <- xgb < otsu(xgb) # Otsu's algorithm to determine best threshold
  xto <- opening(xth, makeBrush(3, shape = "diamond"))
```

A binary (thresholded) image has been produced and cleaned up to identify objects as shown here.

[image: preprocessed and thresholded image]

```
# Create object mask with unique integer for each object
  xm <- bwlabel(xto)
# plot(colorLabels(xm)) # optional code to visualize the objects
```

In addition to the rudimentary image process, some "object processing" can be applied as shown here. Objects along the edge are not going to be of interest so they are removed. Similarly, artifacts that give rise to horizontal (wide) streaks can be removed as well.

```
# Drop objects touching the edge
  nx <- dim(xm)[1]
  ny <- dim(xm)[2]
  sel <- unique(c(xm[1,], xm[nx,], xm[,1], xm[,ny]))
  sel <- sel[sel != 0]
  xm <- rmObjects(xm, sel, reenumerate = TRUE)

# Drop exceptionally wide objects (33% of image width) 
  major <- computeFeatures.moment(xm)[,"m.majoraxis"]
  sel <- which(major > nx/3)
  xm <- rmObjects(xm, sel, reenumerate = TRUE)
```

The following logic identifies the center of mass for each object with the `computeFeatures.moment` function of `EBImage`. It seems that the main symbols will be along a horizontal line while the candidate object will be above that line (lower y-value in `EBImage` Image object). An alternative approach would be to find objects stacked on one another, i.e., objects with similar x-values.

For the examples I explored, one standard deviation away from the median y-value for the center of mass appears to be sufficient to identify candidate object. This is used to determine the limits shown below. Of course, this logic should be adjusted as dictated by the actual data.

```
# Determine center of mass for remaining objects
  M <- computeFeatures.moment(xm)
  x <- M[,1]
  y <- M[,2]

# Show suggested limit on image (y coordinates are inverted)
  plot(img)
  limit <- median(y) - sd(y)
  abline(h = limit, col = "red")

# Show centers of mass on original image
  ok <- y < limit
  points(x[!ok], y[!ok], pch = 16, col = "blue")
  points(x[ok], y[ok], pch = 16, col = "red")
```

The image shows the segmented objects after having discarded objects along the edge. Red shows the candidate, blue shows the non-candidates.

[image: candidates with mark-up]

Because some licenses have two symbols above the dash, the following code selects the leftmost of possible candidates, expands the object mask and returns a rectangular crop of the image that can be passed to `ocr()`.

```
# Accept leftmost (first) of candidate objects
  left <- min(x[which(ok)])
  sel <- which(x == left)
  
# Enlarge object mask and extract the candidate image
  xm <- dilate(xm, makeBrush(7, "disc"))
  ix <- range(apply(xm, 2, function(v) which(v == sel)))
  iy <- range(apply(xm, 1, function(v) which(v == sel)))
  xx <- ix[1]:ix[2]
  yy <- iy[1]:iy[2]

# "Return" selected portion of image
  ans <- img[xx, yy] # this is what can be passed to tesseract
  plot(ans, interpolate = FALSE)
```

Here is the unscaled and extracted candidate image from example 1:     [image: answer 1]

#### Another sample image

[image: sample 2]

The same code applied to this example gives the following:    [image: answer 2]

With a few more checks for errors and for illogical conditions, the code could be assembled into single function and applied to the list of 5000 files! But of course that assumes they are properly formatted, etc. etc.

Comment: Thnx for the response David O! Sounds really good! 
I am going to go through your explanation even further in the coming days, but I will definitely try it out.

Comment: Good luck! I look forward to seeing if and how it works for you. By the way, I corrected a sneaky error in my code! `1` was changed to `sel`. Be sure to use the updated version.

Comment: Hello David,  I was on vacation, so took a little time before trying. But the code works good on some pictures. But with a lot of pictures the quality of the picture is to bad. With some pictures bwlabel could not distinguish the objects well and with some pictures h text mining (cat (ocr)) could not read the figure well.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how it worked. With real-world images, the image processing before feature extraction is probably the most critical step. In my example, the step labeled “rudimentary image process” should be replaced with more appropriate code for your images. (R can work but may not be the best for this...) This has to be tailored to your images, but a Sobel filter to enhance edges and/or an unsharp mask for local contrast enhancement might be good for JPEGS. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

[What with the existance of multiple layouts for Dutch license plates](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nederlands_kenteken#Sidecodes), I'm not sure if you just can hardcode a method to extract a duplication value. Also you don't mention if every image you have always has the same quality and/or orientation/scale/skew/etc.

You could in theory apply a [Convolutional Neural Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) that categorizes license plates in a several categories. (0 for n/a, 1 for 1, 2 for 2, etc.) However I am not familiar with related packages in R, so I won't be able to point you to some.

Comment: Thnx for response CZorio! Sorry for the missing information. In this research we focus only on passenger cars. These 5000 pictures have almost al the same layouts as the example.

Comment: CNN is an good option i think, maybe i can use tensor flow for it. But the risk with CNN on the whole photo is that neural network is gonna tru to  find a pattern in the numbers and letters. While if you only need to apply cnn or ocr to the duplicate code then I guess it will be a good model earlier